# can i break chrome extension content security policy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i want to make a chrome extension that contains a website inside it, as written in here [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) inline scripts and events like onclick won't work to ensure security to the user from a script injection.
but what if all of the users who will use the extension trusting it? 
the main question is how to enable inline scripts and events in chrome extension regardless security things

Comment: Is the sandbox sufficient?  http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval.html

Comment: Hi, most of things you can do with inline script, you can do with a separate script too.  Like adding listeners with element.addEventListener('click', function).  Are you shure this policy is an impossible obstacle for you?